# Though I included the -g flag, gdb does not give the line number for an error

Tags: c, multithreading, gdb

I have encountered a segfault in a c program which I am writing. Usually, I am able to run the program in gdb, which will let me know which line the issue is occurring on, so that I am able to fix it. However, for whatever reason, this time no line number is provided with the error.

What reasons might cause gdb to fail to return the line number of a segfault?

I usually compile with -g, in this case I have tried -ggdb as well, which yields the same results. Gdb does say that the threads exited with code 3221225477, which is a segfault, but this doesn't really provide enough information to be useful.

Edit: The output from gdb:

```
[Thread 10064.0x2aa0 exited with code 3221225477]
[Thread 10064.0x2c3c exited with code 3221225477]
[Thread 10064.0x1e40 exited with code 3221225477]
[Inferior 1 (process 10064) exited with code 030000000005]
```

Compiler options (from the sublime text 2 build file):

```
gcc $file_base_name.c -std=gnu99 -I../zdk -L../zdk -lzdk -lncurses -g -o $file_base_name
```

Edit: It turns out that I was trying to access freed memory. The question still stands though: why didn't gdb tell me which line this was occurring on?

Comment: gdb says the code was 3221225477? Can you post gdb's entire output?

Comment: Sometimes it will segfault inside some code that does not have symbols.  Have you tried running a backtrace (`bt`) to see the rest of the frames in the stack?

Comment: What are the compiler options you used, and how did you try to use gdb?

Comment: `3221225477` is `0xC0000005`. This looks as if you are observing this on Windows ... ;-)

Comment: @paddy I tried `frame`, and `bt` gives the same error: No stack. Is there a way to halt execution before exiting the program?

Comment: And `030000000005` is octal and `0xC0000005` as well.

Comment: Go through the different threads using `thread {1,2, ...}` and for each do a `bt`.

Comment: @alk `Thread ID 1 not known`, I assume that's related to the no stack error from before?

Comment: And BTW, as obviously still in the debugging phase you should ***really*** compile with all warnings on (`-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic`) and continue fixing the code until no more warnings are issued.

Comment: Though you tagged with multithreading, I'm not trying to multithread, and my understanding is that this is not something one does by accident.

Comment: Dare to show some sources, typically a stripped down version procducing the described behaviour?

Comment: As  argument to GCC'S thread command you might try something like  this 10064.0x2aa.  Or do: Info threads.

Comment: Those exit codes look like Windows exception codes rather than segfaults.  You need to figure out how to tell gdb to stop on windows exceptions, which it apparently is not doing by default.  Look into the documentation for your particular windows port of gdb (mingw? cygwin? something else?) and see what it tells you about windows exceptions.  Probably a command you need to issue before you even start the program.

Comment: amongst other things, the line numbers from library functions will never be displayed because that info is not (normally) available.  If you preform a 'bt' command in `gdb` it should give you the call stack back to the last place your code was executing.  That place will have a line number.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, they were definitely segfaults, and I was able to identify the line they were occurring on. As mentioned above, I tried bt.

Comment: If there's no stack information at all, it generally indicates some kind of heap corruption.